# University course references for Market Structure/Industrial Organization

Tags: reference-request, industrial-organisation, markets, firm

Are there any books that are used in University-level courses that contain a detailed analysis of market structure ( Perfect competition , Monopoly and so on)?

Comment: I guess, what you mean is that they are used in University-level courses, and I think its useful to have a more specific title so that people know wha you are asking right off the bat.

Answer (score 1):

The standard, if somewhat aged textbook for graduate study of industrial organization is

[The Theory of Industrial Organization](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/theory-industrial-organization) by Jean Tirole.

Tirole has the merit of tacking issues around market structure in a quite direct fashion. A slightly more modern text is

[Industrial Organization: Markets and Strategies](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/economics/industrial-economics/industrial-organization-markets-and-strategies) by Paul Bellflamme and Martin Peitz

A less advanced text that can be downloaded for free is

[Industrial Organization: A Strategic Approach](https://works.bepress.com/jeffrey_church/23/) by Jeffrey R Church and Roger Ware

---

It's worth mentioning that Industrial Organization is typically not encountered as a stand-alone course until the late stages of an undergraduate degree or until graduate level, so books on this subject will typically be more advanced than a standard econ101 text.